# Template function taking any functor and returning the type of the functor return

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, stdbind

I have an member function, which receives some data from serial port and few parser functions in the same class, which then parse recieved data to specific format. All the parse functions take same parameter. What I want is to pass any kind of parser function to recieve function an to make recieve function return same type as parser returns. 
Wha I have tried:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    template<typename F>
    auto receive(F parser) -> decltype(parser(std::declval(QByteArray)))
    {
        QByteArray response = readAll();
        return parser(response);
    }

    QHash<QString, QVariant> parseHash(QByteArray data);
    QString parseString(QByteArray data);
    void doStuff();
};

void Foo::doStuff()
{
    QHash<QString, QVariant> response = receive(&Foo::parseHash);    // Compilation error

    // Another try..
    response = receive(std::bind(&Foo::parseHash, this, std::placeholders::_1)); // Also compilation error
}
```

In both cases compilation fails with message

```
error: C2893: Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type Foo::receive(F)'
```

With the following template arguments:
'F=QHash (__thiscall Foo::LocalConnector::* )(QByteArray)'

Comment: If your compiler supports C++14, you can omit the `decltype(...)` return type completely and let the compiler infer the return type.

Comment: @Jens note that then it won't be SFINAE-able anymore (but maybe it's not an issue in this case)

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Right, but I think the OP doesn't want any SFINAE here, he just wants a function that returns the same type as his parser function, whatever it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the below snippet:

```
QHash<QString, QVariant> response = receive(&Foo::parseHash);
```

`parseHash` is a non-static member function, hence it requires an implicit object parameter. Otherwise, the expression SFINAE fails, making `receive` a non-viable candidate.

The following should work instead:

```
void Foo::doStuff()
{
    auto callback = std::bind(&Foo::parseHash, this, std::placeholders::_1);

    QHash<QString, QVariant> response = receive(callback);
}
```

Or simply make `parseHash` a static member function.

Also, there's a typo in your expression SFINAE, it should be:

```
decltype(parser(std::declval<QByteArray>()))
```